# Revert to a gem version based on commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

I added this to my Gemfile three days ago:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', git: 'https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass', branch: '3'
```

Today I ran `bundle update`, the gem got updated, and a lot of tests are broken as a result.

Is there a way I can revert back to the gem as it were three days ago? I can look at the commits, but I don't know if I can go back to a certain commit.

Answer (score 3):

`Gemfile.lock` stores the revision used, so if you check out your code from three days ago look there. It should look something like this:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/datamapper/dm-core.git
  revision: 7cc4c145329e81d8b373a37694d050aa197c3699
  branch: release-1.2
  specs:
    dm-core (1.2.1)
      addressable (~> 2.3, >= 2.3.5)
```

Just replace `:branch` in your current `Gemfile` with the above `revision` SHA and run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2):

You can point your `Gemfile` to a specific commit/branch/tag of a Git repo:

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :ref => '4aded'
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :tag => 'v2.3.5'
```

Don't forget to re-run `bundle install`

Source: [Bundler git docs](http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html)

Comment: The asker is doing that already. Their question is how to determine the ref that was being used previously.

Comment: @AbeVoelker _I can look at the commits, but **I don't know if I can go back to a certain commit**._ I would interpret that as wanting to use the specific commit of the **gem** in question; and not a commit in OPs own project. But your way of referring to `Gemfile.lock` works too.

Answer (score 1):

if this update is included in certain commit you just make opposite of that commit by 'git revert' command

```
git revert <that commit hash>
```